# get multiple values for one hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 selectable options, what I need is some how to get the value from the selected and add it to the hidden field so when submit is clicked it takes the value into the php and depending on the value each one will have a different outcome to an mysql database insert/update.

I have it working with code I have but...It is getting the 1st option every time by default, It is not getting a value depending on what is selected.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".crimeSelect").hover(
    function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('isSelected') == false) { $(this).css('opacity', 0.80); }
    }
);
$(".crimeSelect").click(function() {
    $("#selec1").val($(this).attr('crimeid'));
    $(this).css('opacity', 1.00);
    $('.crimeSelect.isSelected').removeClass('isSelected').css('opacity', 0.40);
    $(this).addClass('isSelected');

});
});
```

HTML

```
<td class="content">
  <input type="hidden" value="x" name="Crime" id="selec1"/>
  <div crimeid="9" name="9" class="crimeSelect" style="cursor:pointer;opacity:0.40;margin:auto;"><img src="images/crimes/Kidnapthepope-Title.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:auto;"/></div>
</td>
<td class="content">
  <div crimeid="10" name="10" class="crimeSelect" style="cursor:pointer;opacity:0.40;margin:auto;"><img src="images/crimes/Pickpocketadoctor-Title.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:auto;"/></div>
</td>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['Crime'])) {
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Account_Character SET money='0' WHERE username="$username") or die(mysqli_error());
```

The PHP is just a small example but this is what I am having the issue with, putting value from selected into hidden input then passing to the PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using the `event.target` to get the attribute instead of `this selector`? like `var target = $( event.target) ` then `target.attr('crimeid');` inside the callback function

Comment: No I haven't, Wasn't sure if can be done just through the html/php side of things and I am not to great with JS/JQUERY. How would I do it. in regards to that and form/php

Comment: The PHP Code missing a closing bracket atlast add `}` atlast

Comment: I know i realised after but that is not the issue, I have the extra bracket in my code just didn't get it in the copy and paste to here. as said that php is just an example of what I wanted to do but each option would be different and can get more into the outcome of the selected once I know how to pass value from selected to the hidden field and then pick up on the php side.

Comment: Please use prepared statements and don't just randomly insert strings (with potentially user input) in your query. Unless [little Bobby](https://xkcd.com/327/) is your friend, of course.

Comment: I don't I have a function and wrap them in a function, again PHP was only a example of what I intended to do. Thanks for the tip though but no need. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){



   $(".crimeSelect").click(function(event) {
      alert($(event.target).attr('crimeid'));
       $("#selec1").val($(event.target).attr('crimeid'));
       $(this).css('opacity', 1.00);
        $('.crimeSelect.isSelected').removeClass('isSelected').css('opacity', 0.40);
       $(this).addClass('isSelected');

         });
     });
```

Comment: pay attention to the  callback function, parameter 'event', which comes with a `.target` property which is The DOM element that initiated the event. this is used because the  click event depends on the `event bubbling`

Comment: Alert pops up and says undefined?

Comment: if remove the alert the page will refresh on submit but does nothing. sorry no good when it comes to this language, just want to get the value from is selected and put it or update the hidden field value to then use on the php side.

Comment: sorry, wasnt around to follow this up, the likely reason the pagge is poping up an undefined is because your clicking the image rather than the div, remember your image has no crimeid attribute ! try adding the crimeid attribute to the image

Comment: I did it check my answer below, Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with loads of messing about was one line of code had to do

```
$(".crimeSelect").click(function() {
    $("#selec1").val($(this).attr('crimeid'));
    $(this).css('opacity', 1.00);
    $('.crimeSelect.isSelected').removeClass('isSelected').css('opacity', 0.40);
    $(this).addClass('isSelected');
    $('input[name=Crime]').val($(this).attr('crimeid'));

});
```

Then from the PHP pick up the HTML input name to check value and get going from there :)